# Accessing JSON Array of strings

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

My problem is that I have a JSON column with a key which contains an array of string values. If I access it with array notation:

```
-- JSON Key = "infoProvided":["FullName","Contact Information"]

select top 1 json_value(textarea,'$.infoProvided[0]') from checklist

-- result

(No column name)
FullName

-- expected

(No column name)
FullName,Contact Information
```

I need to get all possible values in the array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: I had to edit your JSON as it was missing the open and closing curly braces.

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(1000) = '{"infoProvided":["FullName","Contact Information"]}';

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON ( @json, '$.infoProvided' );
```

Returns

```
+-----+---------------------+------+
| key |        value        | type |
+-----+---------------------+------+
|   0 | FullName            |    1 |
|   1 | Contact Information |    1 |
+-----+---------------------+------+

SELECT STRING_AGG ( [value], ',' ) AS InfoList FROM OPENJSON ( @json, '$.infoProvided' );
```

Returns

```
+------------------------------+
|           InfoList           |
+------------------------------+
| FullName,Contact Information |
+------------------------------+

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON ( @json, '$' );
```

Returns

```
+--------------+------------------------------------+------+
|     key      |               value                | type |
+--------------+------------------------------------+------+
| infoProvided | ["FullName","Contact Information"] |    4 |
+--------------+------------------------------------+------+

SELECT JSON_QUERY ( @json, '$.infoProvided' );
```

Returns

```
+------------------------------------+
|          (No column name)          |
+------------------------------------+
| ["FullName","Contact Information"] |
+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks so bloody much!! I didn't want to disappoint my boss this morning ;)